# How can I click on a button that has "data-cy" attribute in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

There is a div with `data-cy="169-small-control-button"`.

How could I click on it just like you can click on id:

```
await page.click('#169-small-control-button');
```

Edit: found the answer:

```
await page.click('div[data-cy="169-small-control-button"]');
```